# Add more space between cells in a table

Tags: tables, spacing

I'd like to add more space between the cells of the table below. I've tried the command `[2ex]` after `\\` but this changes the vertical alignment, which I'd like to be centered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{ } \\
Text text text text & Text text text text & Text text text text & Text text text text \\\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Text text text}
& Text text text text & Text text text text & Text text text text \\[2ex]
& Text text text text & Text text text text & Text text text text \\[2ex]\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Text text text}
& Text text text text & Text text text text & Text text text text \\[2ex]
& Text text text text & Text text text text & Text text text text \\[2ex]\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to add space between the column, the rows or both?

Comment: have you seen [Column padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672) ?

Comment: please let us know if my link resolves the issue- if so, we might vote to close to help keep the site tidy :)

Answer (score 2):

The following simple example shows several alternatives depending on your intent:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent Default settings:\\
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
column1a & column2a & column3a \\
\hline
column1b & column2b & column3b \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{36pt}

\noindent Changing \verb+\tabcolsep+ (default value: \texttt{6pt}):\\
{
\addtolength\tabcolsep{10pt}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
column1a & column2a & column3a \\
\hline
column1b & column2b & column3b \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\vspace{36pt}

\noindent Using the \verb+@{...}+ syntax to add space individually:\\
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{25pt}}cc}
\hline
column1a & column2a & column3a \\
\hline
column1b & column2b & column3b \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{36pt}

\noindent Changing \verb+\arraystretch+ factor:\\
{
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{25pt}}cc}
\hline
column1a & column2a & column3a \\
\hline
column1b & column2b & column3b \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\vspace{36pt}

\noindent Using the optional argument for \verb+\\+ in a \textit{per-row} basis:\\
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{25pt}}cc}
\hline
column1a & column2a & column3a \\[2ex]
\hline
column1b & column2b & column3b \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank very much for your help. Chaning the arraystrecth parameter is the best option for my purposes. Thanks again! Best, Beth.

Comment: @beth_calister You're welcome. Since this question is a duplicate (of the question cmhughes linked to in his comment), most probably it will be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

write before `\begin{tabular}`

```
\addtolength\tabcolsep{5pt}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford changing environment, `tabu` instead of `tabular` and specify `\tabulinesep=^Xmm_Ymm` at the beginning of your document. Use the same value for `X` and `Y` to preserve the vertical alignment.

Comment: that version of `tabu` is no more supported and the new one will be published sometimes, whenever this may be

Comment: @Herbert I did not know that. Where may I find official statements about the support provided to the various packages?

Comment: in the newsgroups c.t.t and f.c.t.t